# Generate Black frames between concatenated videos ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, concatenation

I'm trying to concatenate 2 videos together using `ffmpeg concat`, but I want to have there be 2 seconds of black between the 2 videos.

The problem is that whenever I've tried to generate a black video and concatenated it in, the properties never match my input video exactly, and so the concatenation is all broken - the audio is broken or the frames change at the wrong speed or generally concatenation fails.

Here's the output of `ffmpeg -i my_input_video1.mp4` (and is identical for my_input_video2.mp4):

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'input_vid1.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.3.100
  Duration: 00:00:03.07, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 191 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 480x270, 116 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn, 59.94 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 63 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
```

How can I generate a 2 second black video with these properties so that it can be concatenated with my input videos?

Comment: As a side note, I have tried 2 things actually - generating a video from black frames that has identical properties to my input videos, and trying to use some filter to black out a copy of my input video so I get out a black video with identical properties. Neither has worked for me, but I'm not an ffmpeg expert

Comment: Which concat method are you using?

Comment: @Gyan I'm using `ffmpeg -f concat -i mylist.txt -c copy output.mp4`